# APOC extension does not work correctly

Tags: neo4j

I downloaded the latest release of the APOC extension here:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/3.0.4.1

I use Neo4j 3.0.4 on Windows. I copied the jar file to the neo4j\plugin folders (the install directory of Neo4j as well as the database plugin directory).

I can call some APOC functions like that:

```
CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce('21 rue Paul Bellamy 44000 NANTES FRANCE') YIELD location
RETURN location.latitude, location.longitude
```

but other things doesnt work. E. g.:

```
CALL apoc.spatial.showConfig()
```

shows: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.spatial.showConfig` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Additionally:

```
:GET /db/data/ext
```

does not list the APOC extension.

What I am doing wrong? I thought, I just have to drop it to the plugins folder...

EDIT1:
I found this link: http://indexoutofrange.com/Neo4jStoredProceduresWindows/
I will try and share my results...

EDIT2: I tried the link above. I created the short example to use

```
CALL apoc.spatial.sortPathsByDistance(paths)
```

but it did not work.

EDIT3:
The procedure is called now apoc.spatial.sortByDistance... The documentation is not up to date. You have to look in the code of the repository...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `apoc.spatial.showConfig()` procedure listed in the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_spatial). Browsing the classes in the [spatial package](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/tree/3.0.4.1/src/main/java/apoc/spatial) of the 3.0.4.1 tag doesn't show an undocumented procedure with that name either.

Searching the history shows it did exist but was [removed](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/commit/c31f64623551e845607c0bf53413be07ae3732f4#diff-f9860f49bddc74d41adc126470e66d1bL244) in May.

Procedures are not extensions, which is why they don't show up when you call `:GET /db/data/ext` in the browser. Unmanaged extensions don't show up there either, by the way.

Comment: Hey, I was looking at: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_configuring_custom_geocode_provider   If this is not the current version, sorry.
Ok, I didnt know, that they are not listed as extensions. I did not usw procedures and extensions up to now... Thank you.

Comment: Where can I find the current version of the documentation? Your link as well as the link in github links to the documentation I used. So it should be the latest one. But this documentation does include apoc.spatial.showConfig() for example. I was just wondering because I cannot call apoc.spatial.sortPathsByDistance neither.

Comment: It's a community project, so documentation is probably lower excitement than new features. You can always start [bringing them up to date yourself](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/tree/master/docs), though. :)

Comment: That was no accusation, I understand that. I just wanted to clarify for other readers. But actually thats a good idea. I am very new to Neo4j at all but this could be a good starting point to start community work! :)

Comment: oh, it wasn't taken as an accusation, I was thinking about doing the same myself, but I don't work with `apoc` that often :)

Comment: Yes, the documentation is inconsistent: the procedure is not listed for the package (my link) but is used in the extended documentation (your link).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help up to now.
@Tore Eschliman: I know, everything is fine. :)